# Did Visual Studio 2010 break "Project Dependencies" between C++ projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2008, if I had a solution containing multiple C++ projects, I could make them depend on each-other and correctly link by using the "Project Dependencies" option. This fixed up the build order and also made (e.g.) the main application project link against the static library outputs.

In Visual Studio 2010, this doesn't seem to work. Did Visual Studio 2010 change the way this works?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. You also need to [add a Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcprerelease/thread/3bb7fe8d-42d8-4a54-aa75-5ae523d5868b) to the depended-upon project. This is not just for managed C++ (or C++/CLI) applications any more.

The Visual C++ Team Blog has an entry about this: [Flexible Project-to-Project References](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2010/05/03/flexible-project-to-project-references.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Roger. I was trying to do that in 2008 and was annoyed by the lack of consistency in project referencing