# Visual Studio 2010 not autolinking static libraries from projects that are dependencies as it should be supposed to

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build

- Create a new solution with a C++ console command-line project
- Create a new project, a C++ static library
- Make the command-line project depend on the library
- Make sure "Link Library Dependencies" is turned on in Configuration => Linker => General (it is by default)
- Visual Studio will still not link the library.

How can I fix this? It worked in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This still works, but was [changed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/02/16/project-settings-changes-with-vs2010.aspx) in VS 2010:

> "With VS2010, we stopped supporting project dependencies defining implicit references and we also introduced a new way of defining project dependencies at the project level. Since a project reference and a project dependency are close concepts, both applying to a project, it made sense to have them represented together, in a consistent way, in the project file. As you will see in the snippets below, the only difference between a project reference definition and a project dependency definition consists in metadata that defines the output assembly inclusion/exclusion into/from the main project link command line.
>   Although we did not remove the “Project Dependencies” dialog, we recommend defining new project dependencies via the “Framework and References” dialog. You need to set the “Reference Assembly Output” property in the property page UI to false for a project dependency and to true for a project reference."

Just right-click on the console project, select "Properties->Common Properties->Framework and References->Add New Reference" and add the static library project; also check that "Link Library Dependencies" is True on the right hand side. Seems to work for debug and release builds. You learn something new every day. ;)

Comment: You need to add projects to the current solution? Whats the point of having static libraries then?

Comment: @UtkarshSinha You don't "need" to add the static library project to the solution, but if it's not part of the solution, Visual Studio can't build it. If you have a pre-built static library that is not part of the solution, this entire question does not apply to you.

Comment: I'd say "[M$ makes sure we need to learn something new every day](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000339.html)" >:)

Comment: For future spelunkers: this has been changed post-VS2010. Right-click on the "References" node in the project within the Solution Explorer and add the dependent project. I suppose if you have an out-of-solution project you will have to add the .lib manually via Properties->Linker->Input or use a shared project.

Comment: It is worth noting that for MSVC 14 (2015) one looks under project's "Add->Reference..." and then clicking on the needed dependencies

Comment: This page provides some insight into the Link Library Dependencies option: May 3rd, 2010. Amit Mohindra. Flexible Project-to-Project References
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/flexible-project-to-project-references/

Answer (score 25):

They changed the UI for adding C++ project dependencies in VS2010, but oddly enough, without removing the old UI, or in any way indicating that it no longer works.

To create the dependency in VS2010, you need to use "Add New Reference" (can be found in project properties), and maybe also in the project's right-click menu (don't have VS here to check)

The old "Project Dependencies" dialog is basically broken now.

Comment: Also, the dialog says something about .Net frameworks, even for pure C++ projects. Microsoft clearly hasn't done even basic UI testing on solutions with multiple projects. It's really giving off the impression that Visual Studio is only intended for Hello, World sized projects.

Comment: The old UI used to do _two_ things, and these have been seperated.  The old UI still does compile dependency ordering, the project properties now handles linking.  Just because A needs to be compiled before B doesn't mean B should link with A.

Comment: VS 2017 and IT IS STILL BROKEN!@#$!@#$!@#$ but not removed.
JFC. >:(

Comment: @Mordachai it's still needed for project order

Answer (score 8):

For MSVC 14 (2015 version) right-click on the project, then `"Add->Reference..."` and check all the needed dependencies.

Yes, it has changed somewhere between 2010 and 2015 versions. Fun!

And if you are looking to link a project that has resources in it - you need to specify the `.res` file directly in the list of linker input dependencies (project's properties dialog box) as it doesn't get picked up by the above configuration.

**UPDATE**

Still the same (new) behavior in MSVC 2017

Comment: Just letting you all know that this also works for MSVC 2017.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the old UI (dependencies) affects build order for Visual Studio, when building from within the IDE, for info. The new project configuration system embeds the references in each project file so that you can build from outside the IDE (whereas in previous versions, you could not, because you would not get automatic linking for dependencies, since dependencies were only done at the solution level).

There are also some issues with more complex projects in the new system; specifically, all resulting binary projects need to have explicit references to every dependent library to build correctly, whereas previously they could be effectively inherited from other dependent libraries. Same underlying cause, though.