# Static linking with OpenSSL

Tags: c, windows, openssl, linker

We have a project really similar to the one reported in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437538/vs2010-static-linking-issue) question where OpenSSL is the starting point of `lib B`. When compiling the executable (`Exe 1`), the problem is that we are getting some linking issues that seems to be related to OpenSSL linking.

```
(cryptlib.obj) LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __alloca_probe_16 referenced in function _OPENSSL_isservice
(bss_file.obj) LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __alloca_probe_16 
(b_print.obj)  LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __ftol2_sse referenced in function _roundv
```

Compiling the library doesn't give any error whatsoever. I'm curious to know where are located these functions so that I can add the correct references in the project.

I'm running on Windows 7 with a 64 bits proc, if that can make any difference :)

**Edit1**
Those are errors when compiling in Win32 with VS2010.

**Edit2**
The OpenSSL lib (libeay32.lib) was also compiled with `nasm` for VS2010 (for Win32).

**Edit3**
If someone could point out a link to build OpenSSL with VS2010 (vc2010) or VS2008 compiler, that would also be helpfull (other than pointing to the InstallW** files in OpenSSL)

**Edit4**
We are also using the Windows DDK 2003, if it can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps I took to solve the issue :

**Solving the __alloca_probe_16 linking error**

Since we *also* have Visual Studio 2008 installed we used some `obj` files to fix this issue. `alloca16.obj` is present in four different directories under the Visual Studio 2008 folder (which should be something like `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/crt/src/intel/XXX_lib` where `XXX` might be `dll`, `mt`, `xdll` or `xmt`. Note that I'm not quite sure what is the difference between any of them).

Adding this path to the `Linker > General > Addtionnal Library Directories` under the `Properties` panel of the project and adding alloca16.obj to the `Linker > Input > Addtional Dependencies` solved the issue.

**Solving the __ftol2_sse linking error**

This one is a little bit tricky. Configuring OpenSSL with `no-sse2` flag *seems* like it would fix the problem... but not as of version `1.0.0d`. I created a new header file which contains this :

```
extern "C" { 
   long _ftol( double ); 
   long _ftol2_sse( double dblSource ) { return _ftol( dblSource ); }
}
```

(as shown on [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=60003) site)

Comment: That site (http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=60003) is no longer available...