# MSBuild.exe doesn't respect /MT compiler flag?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I was surprised to see that after switching our build system from VS2008 to VS2010 our application now complains that MSVCR100.dll is missing at runtime.  I checked our project's build options and we are specifying Multi-threaded (/MT) for the Runtime Library.  However, when we build using the GUI, the DLL is statically linked and the error does not appear.  The error only happens when we build using MSBuild.exe from the command line.

I compared the command lines, and they are almost the same, both specify /MT:

**VS2010 GUI:**

> /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oi /Oy- /GL /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "GSL_DLL" /D "WIN32" /D >"_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0710" /D "__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS" /D >"_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm- /EHsc /MT /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t >/Zc:forScope /Fp"Release\Temp\ourProject.pch" /Fa"Release\Temp\" /Fo"Release\Temp\" >/Fd"Release\Temp\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue

**MSBuild.exe:**

MSBuild.exe "%WORKSPACE%\OurProject.vcxproj" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release

> /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oi /Oy- /GL /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D GSL_DLL /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _USRDLL /D _VC80_UPGRADE=0x0710 /D __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS /D _WINDLL /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MT /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope > /Fo"Release\Temp\" /Fd"Release\Temp\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue

I have seen some posts about [VS2010 static linking not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437538/vs2010-static-linking-issue), however my project builds and links just fine.  It is not until runtime that it cannot find the required DLL.  Installing the VS2010 runtime or shipping with the runtime are options we are trying to avoid.

Thanks!

Comment: Does something like dependency walker show that your .exe has a direct dependency on `msvcrt100.dll` or is it some other binary that actually has the dependency?

Comment: You are right, it was some other binary that had the dependency.  Thanks!