# Can i make a small program portable by statically linking all the libraries in vs2010?

Tags: static, linker, imagemagick, portability

I have a small program using imageMagick library. I added necessary library dependencies and set Runtime Library to /MT, and it complied and ran well on my Win7, but when it ran on another computer it asked for CORE_RL_Magick++_.dll !? What's wrong? 
I intended to make a small portable exe which can run on others' computer, i thought the easiest and clean way is to statically link all the necessary library in one single exe so that others can just click-and-run. But the VS2010 seemed didn't do what i want.
Is it possible to statically link all necessary libraries ? If so, how can i get this in vs2010? Why the exe ask for dll after these configuration? 
I was bothered for quite a long time, i would appreciate it if you can give me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010 has some changes in Projects settings including the static linking , you may find the proper way here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/02/16/project-settings-changes-with-vs2010.aspx

Comment: I have read that, but i am not very familiar with VS2010, so i cannot  fully understand the article you recommended. Could you tell me what configurations i should make to statically link all the necessary libraries? Thank you.

Comment: have a look at this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795567/visual-studio-2010-not-autolinking-static-libraries-from-projects-that-are-depen