# Embed POCO static library into another one

Tags: c++, static-linking, poco-libraries

I'm developing an SDK (as dynamic and static lib) using Poco, and I would like to embed the Poco static libs into my one to avoid the end user to setup and link the Poco enviroment.
The C/C++ settings for the MySDKd.LIB are:

```
/I"..\..\..\include" 
/I"..\..\..\src" 
/I"D:\lib\boost_1_53_0\" 
/I"..\..\..\thirdparty" 
/I"..\..\..\thirdparty\protobuf\include\" 
/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- 
/D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_LIB" 
/D "WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN" /D "_MBCS" 
/D "POCO_STATIC" /D "POCO_NO_AUTOMATIC_LIBS" 
/D "IBPP_WINDOWS" 
/Gm /EHa /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope 
/Fp"Debug\MySDKd.pch" /Fa"Debug\" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" 
/Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue
```

And the linker settings are:

```
/OUT:"D:\src\MySDK\win32\VS2010\..\..\..\bin\static\MySDKd.lib" 
"libprotobufd.lib" 
"PocoFoundationmdd.lib" 
"PocoUtilmdd.lib" 
"PocoNetmdd.lib" 
"PocoXMLmdd.lib" 
/LIBPATH:"D:\lib\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib" 
/LIBPATH:"D:\lib\poco-1.5.1-all\lib" 
/LIBPATH:"D:\src\MySDK\lib" 
/NOLOGO /NODEFAULTLIB
```

Now, when I build a simple test project (which use the sdk), I get the linker error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'PocoFoundationmdd.lib'
```

unless I add to the linker path of my test project the Poco\lib folder.
But this lib should now be a part of my MySDKd.lib, right?

When I build my SDK, moreover, I get this linker warning:

```
PocoFoundationmdd.lib(ByteOrder.obj) : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library

PocoFoundationmdd.lib(String.obj) : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library

PocoFoundationmdd.lib(SignalHandler.obj) : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library

PocoFoundationmdd.lib(WS2_32.dll) : warning LNK4006: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in PocoFoundationmdd.lib(IPHLPAPI.DLL);  second definition ignored

PocoFoundationmdd.lib(WS2_32.dll) : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library

PocoXMLmdd.lib(XMLString.obj) : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library
```

Searching around, I found this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/07/21/linker-warning-lnk4221-and-some-tips-to-avoid-it.aspx)  (see the section 'Build a static library with other static libraries') but referring to this case, I don't understand why this happen.

Is this warning may be the cause to my problem?

Regards,
Daniele

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but did you put *.lib file into your project **D:\src\MySDK\win32\VS2010** if not than put them into your project.

Comment: I don't think this will solve the problem. The path for the libs is specified into the linker property page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that feature was changed in VS 2010. What you are trying to do seems not to work since VS 2010. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795567/visual-studio-2010-not-autolinking-static-libraries-from-projects-that-are-depen) and related [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/02/16/project-settings-changes-with-vs2010.aspx) for more details. I have no first hand experience with it, but [make-it-so](https://code.google.com/p/make-it-so/wiki/MergingStaticLibraries) provides a tool that allegedly can do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi @Alex, sorry for my late answer but I switched to another project for a while..moreover, I try to use the lib command in the post-build (as in the page you suggested) but it does not work. Also I don't know how make-it-so can help me. I haven't yet found a solution!