# vs2010 dll linking without a reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a project. That project references a .dll (d1). That .dll uses objects from another .dll (d2). I added a reference to d1 to the project, d2 is not referenced. Would it build?

If it builds would that mean that d2 is not used by d1? (so the above statement is wrong, d1 doesn't use any object of d2)

Please don't downvote, i'm sure that it is not possible - from where should the linker get the library if it's not referenced in the project, it is not even on the hard drive. And if it is possible just tell me how.

Comment: The dependencies of your dependencies are not required for your project to **build**. They are required for it to run, though. Your project only needs to know what d1 provides. When the project is run, d1 is loaded, and it should then try to load d2.

Comment: Please post this as answer, i accept it, it is right. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependencies of your dependencies are not required for your project to build. They are required for it to run, though. Your project only needs to know what d1 provides. When the project is run, d1 is loaded, and it should then try to load d2.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below links:

[Visual Studio 2010 not autolinking static libraries from projects that are dependencies as it should be supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795567/visual-studio-2010-not-autolinking-static-libraries-from-projects-that-are-depen)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/bcfd6cd1-0fcf-4238-be93-59162e5d8230/

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/638534/unresolved-externals-when-build-a-vc-project-with-chained-static-lib-dependencies#details

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/05/03/flexible-project-to-project-references.aspx