# VS2012(C++) Project: can't set "Link Library Dependencies" to True

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

So I am trying to set the static lib projects for my main project so that I don't need to specify the folder with the .lib file. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795567/visual-studio-2010-not-autolinking-static-libraries-from-projects-that-are-depen) how to do it.But when I set **"Framework and References"** -> **"Link Library Dependencies"** to **"True"** and click **"Apply"** it gets reset to "False". Why?

UPDATE:

As Hans Passant explained,those settings exist only for a mixed mode.But what I don't understand then,why in my case as long as "Link Library Dependencies" was set to false the libs wouldn't link automatically?Finally,btw,I was able to set it to True by removing and adding those libs back as reference and Setting Linker->General->Link Library Dependencies -YES .Now I don't need to explicitly specify lib paths in linker for these libs.But again,I am not sure that's the way to go?

Comment: Is the static library set as a dependency of the exe or dll main project?

Comment: It is static library project which I set dependent to the exe project via Properties - > References

Comment: This is by design, the setting only is meaningful for a mixed-mode assembly.  Avoid asking an XY question, explain the actual problem you are trying to solve.  If it links the .lib correctly, the intent, then you don't have a problem.