# Why doesn't Visual Studio 2015 link to a dependent dll project

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015

I used to work with Visual Studio 2008. When created a solution with a cpp application project and a cpp dll project and added a build dependency from the app project to the dll project VS was automatically linking the app to the dll. However, this doesn't seem to be the case with VS 2015. I have to add the lib file manually to the linker inputs. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 not autolinking static libraries from projects that are dependencies as it should be supposed to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795567/visual-studio-2010-not-autolinking-static-libraries-from-projects-that-are-depen)

Comment: @SimonKraemer has your answer, I believe. Also make sure that Linker / General / Link Library Dependencies is set to `Yes`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to [Visual Studio 2010 not autolinking static libraries from projects that are dependencies as it should be supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795567/visual-studio-2010-not-autolinking-static-libraries-from-projects-that-are-depen) almost solved my problem. There is a little differerence: In VS 2015, there is an extra section for references for each project in the project explorer, where the references can be set.