# What does the "Link Library Dependency" linker option actually do in Visual Studio 2010 - 2015 and upwards?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker, dependencies, projects-and-solutions

Up to VS2008, you set your **native C++** project dependencies up in the solution file (`Project Dependencies ...`) and if (by default) the Linker Option

```
Properties -> Linker -> General : Link Library Dependencies = Yes
```

is set, the Visual Studio Build will automatically link in the `.lib` files of all projects (DLLs, LIBs) that this project is dependent on will be "statically" linked in.

---

***Side** Note*: Microsoft changed how the dependencies worked in **VS2010** and you are now supposed to add the dependency directly to the project

```
Common Properties -> Framework and References : (List of depenencies) 

    (each lib/dll has a separate option: 
     Project Reference Properties -> Link Library Dependencies : True|False
```

I'm fine with that. *This is **not** what this question is about.*

(One explanation here: [Flexible Project-to-Project References](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/05/03/flexible-project-to-project-references.aspx).)

---

It is *still* possible however to define project dependencies on the Solution level and the `General` Linker option is also *still* there. However it doesn't work. See:

- [Link Library Dependencies not working?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/163a3b2d-c747-4436-8e5b-2e52b45af1a2/)
- [Did Visual Studio 2010 break "Project Dependencies" between C++ projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704576/did-visual-studio-2010-break-project-dependencies-between-c-projects)
- [Visual Studio 2010 not autolinking static libraries from projects that are dependencies as it should be supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795567/visual-studio-2010-not-autolinking-static-libraries-from-projects-that-are-depend)

  - ["but oddly enough, without removing the old UI, or in any way indicating that it no longer works"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795567/visual-studio-2010-not-autolinking-static-libraries-from-projects-that-are-depend/3796378#3796378)

### and especially see here (acutal *question* follows)

- [MS Connect Bug 586113: "Link Library Dependencies" does not work](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586113/link-library-dependencies-does-not-work#details)

Where Microsoft confirms that the Linker Option doesn't do what the rest of the world's population expects it to do, and adds the following explanation:

> Thanks for reporting this feedback. The issue you are experiencing is
> by design. "Link Library Dependency" is a flag that only dictates
> whether or not to pass the library as an input to the linker. It does
> not find the dependency automatically. As a customer you will have to
> define the depedency manually as you suggest.

Can **anyone explain what that means**, or more to the point: *What does the "Link Library Dependency" linker option actually do in Visual Studio 2010?*

What is an "input to the linker" that isn't actually linked supposed to be?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

2017 Re-Run. Yay.

### TL;DR

This Option **sets the default value**<sup>(a)</sup> for the actual `Link Library Dependecies` on each project reference. If each project reference has `LinkLibraryDependecies` set, then it is in effect meaningless.

However, when adding a new reference, by default (in VS2010 and 2015) the new `<ProjectReference>` element in the `vcxproj` file does *not* have the setting set, so this option is relevant in that it provides the default for all newly added references, as long as their value isn't modified.

(a): It *really* should be the same for all Configurations (Debug/Release) and Platforms (Win32/x64) or things get really complicated.

### Gory details

[Hans pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7685335/321013) that it *appears* to not do anything in VS2010 **as such**. However, this doesn't mean that it actually ain't used by VS/MSBuild.

The crux is how this option is inserted into the `vcxprj` file and how the defaults work for the `<ProjectReference>` setting in the msbuild file.

The setting on the Linker dialog as shown above is inserted as:

[image: Not actually implemented]

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
...
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
...
    </Link>
    <ProjectReference>
      <LinkLibraryDependencies>This option is not used by VS 2010!</LinkLibraryDependencies>
    </ProjectReference>
...
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

And while it *appears* to be somehow grouped together with the `Link` Option, that's just there to confuse you.

What this *actually does* in a given `vcxproj` file (or when coming from a `.props`file), is to **set the default value of the `Link Library Dependencies` Value** for each project dependency on the `Frameworks and References` section in a VS2010 VC settings dialog --

[image: Link Lib in the References 2010]

-- or in the subtree of the VS2015 References --

[image: Link Lib in the References 2015]

And this is relevant, because when you add a new project reference, the default entry in your `vcxproj` file will look like this:

```
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\W32DynLib1\W32DynLib1.vcxproj">
      <Project>{96be134d-acb5-....-....-....bb6fe4a7}</Project>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

You'll notice that the `<LinkLibraryDependecies>true|false</..>` sub element is missing here: This means you "global" setting will actually be used to set the default value.

If your global setting is `false` (or `No`), the project reference won't link in anything. If it's `true`, it will link in.

What's more:

- If this setting, `LinkLibraryDependency`, is completely missing from your settings, **it will default to *true*** (from the `Microsoft.Cpp[.Common].props`file in the MSBuild folder).
- If you happen to have the value `This is not used` in your global setting, *this will be interpreted as true*.
- If you have the value `False is the new truth!`, or maybe `No way` in this setting, it will *also be interpreted as true* by the build.
- The VS2015 GUI will display a warning if it cannot interpret the string here: [image: String value 'False is the new truth!' cannot be translated to any value from type Boolean.]
- The VS2010 GUI will *display* **False** for ALL values, except `false`, even though this is then interpreted as *true* when building the project.

What's even more:

It *seems* that when converting old Solutions with `vcproj` files, the converter will take the old dependencies that were specified in the `sln` and the value of the `vcproj` project's Linker option, and actually set the `LinkLibraryDependency` for each `ProjectReference` it inserts into the new `vcxproj` - thats one reason I thought that this is a dead option for so long - most of our projects have a conversion history dating back to VS2005.

Comment: This page provides some insight into the Link Library Dependencies option: May 3rd, 2010. Amit Mohindra. Flexible Project-to-Project References
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/flexible-project-to-project-references/

Answer (score 38):

You have to give the setting the proper value to bring clarity:

[image]

Comment: Could you please upload the image again? It's gone missing (or is it because i'm behind a firewall?) HAH, it's a firewall issue. In that case, could you please describe what's the solution?

Comment: (!) I have since learned that this answer is incorrect. See my new accepted answer below for the details.

Answer (score 6):

Here the thing is you have to go to, project properties -> common properties -> framework and references and then add new reference to your projects. Then only it will work in VS 2010 not like in early versions of VS

Answer (score 5):

This has to be set in the `Properties / Common / Frameworks and References`

Alternatively you can add something like the thing below in your vcxproj file, of course use the actual project you're referencing and the uuid of that project.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Cpp\Cpp.vcxproj">
        <Project>{c58574bf-9dd8-4cf8-b5b6-6551f2f3eece}</Project>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you also have to set

```
<IgnoreImportLibrary>false</IgnoreImportLibrary>
```

in the REFERENCED project.