# Automatically determine include directories in a Visual Studio 2010 solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

We have a rather large VS 2010 solution that contains several C++ projects depending on each other. Most of the projects create static libraries that are linked in the final build steps.

I now wonder if there is a way to let the VS 2010 build system figure out include and library directories automatically. At the moment, I have to add the include directory of any lib I would like to use in the *Additional include directories* project setting. Is there a better solution to manage static library dependencies without having to specify all those directories manually? As Visual Studio already knows about the dependency between projects, why can't it determine those paths by itself?

Comment: This got broken in VS2010.  Vote here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586113/link-library-dependencies-does-not-work

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the "Link Library Dependency" linker option actually do in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683869/what-does-the-link-library-dependency-linker-option-actually-do-in-visual-stud)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "better way" is to organize your static libraries better so that finding your headers is easier. VS cannot go out and randomly find the *right* headers for you. If it were to even try, there's too great a risk of multiple projects having headers of the same name (in different locations, of course), and the compiler using the wrong one.

Comment: Of course I want to specify the libary interface myself and not make all headers visible. But I would also like to treat the projects as seperate entities without having to add each include directory manually.