# Use STL internally in a static lib with different versions of visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

I'm trying to link my application with a static library built in a different version of Visual Studio (I'm using VS2010 and the lib is built with VS2008).  The static lib uses STL internally and I'm getting linker errors that some basic_string methods cannot be found.

I understand that if the static lib uses STL in its public interface then this is impossible, since the STL objects are binarily incompatible.  But this is not the case.  None of the methods from the lib that I am calling use STL and I am passing no STL objects to the lib.  But internally the static lib uses STL in it's own functions.

It looks like the library does not have the STL code compiled into it, and the linker is trying to link the STL into the internal methods.  My question is is there any way to compile the static lib to statically link against the STL and include all the code inside of it?

I should mention that my own application also uses STL.  But it seems that both versions could be compiled in provided that they are never passed to each other.

Comment: The problem with mixing versions is that the library and class/function names will be the same, so only one version can be linked.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: That shouldn't matter here, though. When he is linking his application, he shouldn't have any dependency on the library's version of the standard library - they have already been resolved when that library was linked. This assumes, of course, that the no `std::string` is being used anywhere in that library's public interface.

Comment: I correct myself! I didn't quiet notice that his is linking to a **static** library. Yes, then it can't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are linking to a **static** library, and this library is dependent on the version *X* of the standard C++ library, then your application needs to be linked with version *X*, in addition to version *Y* you may be using in your application.

Since several exported symbol names of both, version *X* and version *Y* of the standard library will be the same, you end up with a linker error.

Could you wrap the third-party library in a DLL? That would solve the issue.

Comment: This makes sense.  I was thinking if the static lib had its version of the STL linked inside of it, then I don't have to link my application with this version.  But the symbols are still visible since it's not a DLL.  Just like how I can't have a function with the same name as a function inside the static lib.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, there is a linker option "Link Library Dependencies" which is supposed to include any dependecies of a static library with it. But honestly, I'm not sure if this fixes the final linker error, as the symbols will still clash. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683869/what-does-the-link-library-dependency-linker-option-actually-do-in-visual-stud