# LNK1120 error when creating library in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, lnk2019

When building a Visual Studio project I get a bunch of errors resulting in "LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals".  I'm fairly new to Visual Studio C++ - I've been looking around for answers and can't seem to find any that clear up my errors. The project has several static libraries linked via the project properties window (including Geographic.lib).  I'm using Visual Studio 2013, but Geographic.lib was compiled using Visual Studio 2010. The error output is as follows:

```
Creating library C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Save\Playground\MSHDF\\Release64\Miw.Mshdf.Conversion.lib and object C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Save\Playground\MSHDF\\Release64\Miw.Mshdf.Conversion.exp

1>Geographic.lib(UTMUPS.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z)

1>Geographic.lib(PolarStereographic.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z)

1>Geographic.lib(TransverseMercator.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z)

1>Geographic.lib(UTMUPS.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl std::_Mutex::_Lock(void)" (__imp_?_Lock@_Mutex@std@@QEAAXXZ)

1>Geographic.lib(UTMUPS.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::`vbase destructor'(void)" (__imp_??_D?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAXXZ)

1>Geographic.lib(UTMUPS.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl std::_Mutex::_Unlock(void)" (__imp_?_Unlock@_Mutex@std@@QEAAXXZ)

1>Geographic.lib(UTMUPS.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::str(void)const " (__imp_?str@?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@XZ)

1>Geographic.lib(UTMUPS.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(int)" (__imp_??0?$basic_ostringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@H@Z)

1>Geographic.lib(UTMUPS.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::operator+<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??$?HDU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@PEBDAEBV10@@Z)

1>Geographic.lib(UTMUPS.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::operator+<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,char const *)" (__imp_??$?HDU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@AEBV10@PEBD@Z)

1>Geographic.lib(UTMUPS.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::operator+<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??$?HDU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@AEBV10@0@Z)

1>Geographic.lib(UTMUPS.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::operator+<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,char)" (__imp_??$?HDU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@AEBV10@D@Z)

1>C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Save\Playground\MSHDF\\Release64\Miw.Mshdf.Conversion.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I should do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use STL internally in a static lib with different versions of visual studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146943/use-stl-internally-in-a-static-lib-with-different-versions-of-visual-studio)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)