# Visual Studio 2015 C++ solution/project setup for interchangeable dependency use case

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Since Visual Studio 2010 the option to specify C++ project dependencies in the solution is deprecated ([What does the “Link Library Dependency” linker option actually do in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683869/what-does-the-link-library-dependency-linker-option-actually-do-in-visual-stud)).

However hard-linking a library dependency in the project file is not always convenient. I would like to keep the dependency interchangeable.

For example I have a project defining unittests for a set of libraries.
I want to execute the unittests for different versions of the library (each defined in its own vcxproj).
Pre-VS-2010 one solution file could be created for each library dependency, requiring only a single project file for the unittests.
Now the "preferred" way to do it would be to duplicate the unittest project files for each library dependency, which is undesired.

The .lib output of the dependency could be manually added to the "Additional Dependencies" in the linker options, but this feels like a hack.

What is the best practice for modeling these kind of dependencies in Visual Studio 2015?