# Can we refer Native C++ (2010) project in C++/CLR (2022-NetCore runtime) project

Tags: c++, c++-cli, .net-6.0

I have a C++ Native project (Platform Toolset 2010)
Can i add this 2010 C++ project in 2022 C++/CLR project?

I tried adding this project reference, added reference shows yellow triangle in it. Not referred correctly.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683869/what-does-the-link-library-dependency-linker-option-actually-do-in-visual-stud